# What's supposedly "Iterable" isn't

Tags: angular, http, typescript, observable, ionic3

I just have no idea what's going on now. I backed this code against a previous (and actual) project that works. This one has exactly the same code structure, and somehow, is giving me a different output.

Screenshot:

[image: This s***.]

Provider:

```
startRestRequest(routeSlug: string): Observable<any[]> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/' + routeSlug, "super_secret_key=super_secret_key", options)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Class:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Regions');
    this.laravelApiSvc.startRestRequest('regions').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.regions = res;
    });
  }
```

View:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let region of regions">
      <ion-item>{{ region.name_full }}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: As per your log, it looks like your JSON is actually `{ regions: [] }` rather than simply an array. Thus, your code should be `this.regions = res.regions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your class as

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Regions');
    this.laravelApiSvc.startRestRequest('regions').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res.regions));
      this.regions = res.regions;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am an absolute idiot. I've already tried that `res.regions` multiple times before and was giving me an `undefined` exception. Out of frustration, I hastily came here to squawk.

Little did I realize that I was doing `res.region` the entire time __(was missing the `s`!!!)__

Guess I shouldn't stick to foreign naming conventions if I'm already very comfortable with mine. Thanks anyway!